# Identifying and deleting line breaks

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, associative-array, str-replace

I am using cURL with php to parse with DOM some html content. Then I put the content as string in variables and create an array.

Here's my problem, I got something like

```
Array (
[firstname] => John
[lastname] =>


Doe
[occupation] =>
programmer

[location] => not far away
)
```

I got some line breaks that are not caused by `<br>` tags in html. I can see the (blank) line breaks in the code but there's no tag.

I tried to use code like `str_replace('\s', '', $firstname)` before putting it in my associative array but it is not working. I shall add that `preg_replace('\s','', $firstname)` returns `NULL`

Comment: What do you want to do with the line breaks?  Just remove them?

Comment: Yes. But I tried `trim` and `preg_replace` with \s and I cannot get rid of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

str_replace does not accept regular expressions. maybe just trim the array after...

```
$array = array_map( 'trim', $array );
```

---

if this doesn't work then they aren't normal spaces. use...

```
preg_replace( '~^[\s]+|[\s]+$~', '', $firstname );
```

...before adding to the array. you forgot the delimiters.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However this is not working. The result is the same.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this will work as long as your whitespace is generated by the characters listed for the `trim()` function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: I tried this as well before asking my question here. For some other examples I didn't showed here I had to use `substr` because other functions were not deleting line breaks. However this solution is only good if I always have a regular pattern of line breaks, which is not the case.

Comment: @Galen Do you have any suggestion for a regular expression that wouldn't delete space between words to prevent thing like `[Location] => not far away` to be `notfaraway`?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
foreach($array as &$v){
    $v = preg_replace( '/(\n¦\r)+/s', '', $v);
}
```